# Add jpgc dummy sampler in JMeter 4.0

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

Dummy sampler is not present in JMeter version 4.0[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every JMeter version you need to reinstall JMeter's [PluginsManager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

> Download the Plugins Manager [JAR file](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/)  and put it into JMeter's lib/ext directory. Then start JMeter and go to "Options" menu to access the Plugins Manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler) is not a part of JMeter bundle, it's being provided as a plugin. In order to transfer Dummy Sampler plugin from the previous JMeter installation you need to locate `jmeter-plugins-dummy-x.x.jar` file from the `lib/ext` folder  to the `lib/ext` folder of the new JMeter installation. JMeter restart will be required to pick the plugin up.
2. If you don't have access to the previous JMeter installation you can [download the Dummy Sampler from JMeter Plugins website](https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-dummy)
3. Be aware that the recommended way of installing JMeter plugins and keeping them up to date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
4. And last but not the least, according to [JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever the latest version is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.